# How to add a background color to a Container including Expanded in Flutter

Tags: flutter, layout, flutter-layout

I'm currently faced a problem with **layout** in **Flutter** :/

So I want to add a **background color** to a container which embed a **column** Widget with a **SizedBox** & **Expended** widget.

Layout works like a charm without color but an error is showed when I add the **property color** :(

Here is the code:

```
Container(
  color: Colors.white // <- Not working when I add color property
  child: Expanded(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(),
        Expanded()
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
SizedBox(),
```

Here is the error:

[image: error]

For information, here is the layout I want to achieve, I just want to set a background color to the blue container & transparent one to the bottom SizedBox (in order to see the orange background gradient).

[image: layout]

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@iStormz, what you're doing for `Container` color is correct but your use of `Expanded` is incorrect. `Expanded` should be used only within `Row`, `Column` or `Flex`. You have `Expanded` outside of `Column`. Please find more info here - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Answer (score 6):

Here is the layout which you are looking for. The error you getting because expanded needs a flex layout. I am confused with the background color weather you need or not but the layout is achieved in the below code.you can remove the background color if you want

**Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(

                      begin: Alignment.topRight,
                      end: Alignment.bottomLeft,


                      colors: [

                        Color(0xffFFCE00),
                        Color(0xffE86F1C),
                      ],
                    ),
                    border: Border.all(
                        style: BorderStyle.solid, color: Colors.blue)),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                      child: Container(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,//remove color to make it transpatrent
                          child: Center(child: Text("This is Sized Box"))),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.blueAccent,//remove color to make it transpatent
                              border: Border.all(
                                  style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                  color: Colors.white)),
                          child: Center(child: Text("This is Expanded"))),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
                      child: Center(child: Text("This is Sized Box")),
                    ),
                  ],
                ))),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the layout SS

[image: Remove blue color if you need full transparent]

Thanks.I hope this helps you